# clicking <div> pseudo-buttons inside of dynamically appended <li> - why don't they work?

Tags: jquery

So... when I append the `<li>` below into my `<ul>`, none of the `<div>`pseudo-buttons respond when I click them.

```
$('ul').append('<li class="active">'+ $('#input').val() +'<div class="delete"><span class = "icon">x</span></div><div class = "check"><span class = "icon">---</span></div></li>');
```

Yet the buttons respond perfectly if I hard code the exact same `<li>` into my html.

What's the difference?

Here's one of the click functions as an example.

```
$('.delete').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: this question is asked daily !!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: unfortunately I only see related questions in the right-hand column after I post my question

Comment: you can search using site search box , or use google !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `delete` elements are created dynamically, you need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) based event handlers

```
$('ul').on('click', '.delete', function(){
    $(this).parent().fadeOut();
});
```

when you use a normal event registration model `$('.delete').click(..)` it registers the handler to only those elements which already exists in the dom. Newly added elements will not be aware about the handler.

Comment: thanks - I wondered why the other students were using .on instead of .click

Answer (score 0):

Easy. You need attach the event after it has been added to DOM.

```
$('.delete').click(function(){
 $(this).parent().fadeOut();
});
```

The above should be called after you append to UL. if append is dynamic then every time after you append

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose there is a selector which can be any string. In our example, let

```
var selector = '.delete';
```

If you run a code involving

```
$(selector)
```

then it will apply to all the tags matching the selector when the code runs, so your

```
$(selector).click
```

missed your tags because they have not existed when you ran the code.

So you should use the `.on()` instead to register any tags matching the criteria.